Adding a date filter to seachkit report (not case start or end date) but todays (or another point in time date)
I have created a searchkit that looks at the "count" of open cases together with relative "average" rating for cases.  This is grouped by "case owner".  How do I add a filter to this report so that i can pick any previous date to view this data for that date? (or set up so shows 1st of the month for example?)

If you're talking about showing historical values, that might be tricky, because the data isn't necessarily in the database. Or... it is, but not readily available to just pull up in a search. To find out for example, whether a case was open on a particular date means going through the entire history of the case to see when it was opened, closed, reopened, etc.
